# System Variables in vNext release template

Tags: ms-release-management

I have a vNext release template triggered by a TFS build with a component that is running a PowerShell script in a standard environment.

```
write-verbose "ApplicationPath = $($ApplicationPath)" -verbose
write-verbose "ApplicationPathRoot = $($ApplicationPathRoot)" -verbose
write-verbose "BuildDefinition = $($BuildDefinition)" -verbose
write-verbose "BuildDirectory = $($BuildDirectory)" -verbose
```

The script is displaying the system variables described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn834972.aspx#sectionToggle1) but two variables are not displayed (ApplicationPathRoot and BuildDirectory).
TFS and RM are version 12.0.31101.0 (Tfs2013.Update4)

Am I missing something or is a known problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug; see [Team Foundation Server - Build and release management forum discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cebec06-fc51-42f1-8db4-0d71238d5f79/missing-values-for-vnext-release-template-system-variables?forum=tfsbuild) and [related bug at Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1271931/)